# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras' when I can see keras as a module of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to learn neural networks and have been trying to use the library tensorflow. I have downloaded tensorflow via pip and have the version 2.5 installed. However when I run my script it returns AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras' from the line tf.keras.models.Sequential() when looking at the package tensoflow on command prompt I can see the module keras though

The things I have tried from other answers:
-Update tensorflow of which is says requirement already satisfied
-Update pip
-Update python
-Uninstall and reinstall tensorflow
-Downgrade tensorflow to previous version and update it
-Installing keras separately in which when it runs it says it requires tensorflow 2.2 or higher which I have

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have tried all the answers to similar questions that I can find.
Thanks

Comment: did you name your script tensorflow.py ?

Comment: 2 things that you can try are: try your script on google colaboratory to see if the problem it's in your system or in the script, another thing is passing on anaconda if you are not already using it as a dependencies menager

Comment: Thank you for your answers I have tried google colab and it does run fine. Also the script is not called tensorflow.py Please could you explain what you mean by dependencies manager and anaconda. Thanks